# Why does using tuple function while making a tuple give me a error but doing the same using () does not

Tags: python, list, tuples

I was trying to create a tuple with tuple() with its only element being empty list but it gave me an error, 'list' object is not callable

This code gave me error

```
s=tuple(list(),)
print(s)
```

while this code did not give me any error

```
s=([],)
print(s)
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and if I can do this with list and tuple functions

Comment: The code you provided doesn't raise any errors. You are getting an error because you assigned a `list` object either of the variables `tuple` or `list`. Also note, `tuple(list())` **is not the same thing** as `([],)`. This is crucial to understand

Comment: Looks like you've overwritten either `tuple` or `list` with a list.  Either restart your Python interpreter to fix the problem, or try `del tuple` and `del list` to clear out the erroneous value you've assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The `tuple` and `list` functions take a single (optional) iterable argument, not multiple arguments.  You can therefore do any of the following:

```
>>> tuple((list(),))
([],)
>>> tuple([[]])
([],)
>>> tuple(list([list()]))
([],)
```

but you can't pass `tuple` itself multiple comma-separated args:

```
>>> tuple(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 3
```

Passing a single non-iterable arg with a trailing comma (the way you might construct a tuple literal) will similarly give you an error, because the `tuple()` function doesn't work the same way as a tuple literal expression:

```
>>> (1,)
(1,)
>>> tuple(1,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

and passing a single *empty* iterable arg will always get you an empty tuple:

```
>>> tuple(())
()
>>> tuple((),)
()
>>> tuple([],)
()
>>> tuple(list(),)
()
```

Note that it is possible to re-assign the builtin names `tuple` and `list`, which will make using the actual functions difficult:

```
>>> list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

To fix this, `del` the locally assigned name and the built-in one will work again:

```
>>> del list
>>> list()
[]
```

Comment: but that isn't what is causing the error. `tuple(list(),)` is perfectly valid, albeit, a trailing comma in an argument list is bad style (I didn't downvote, btw)